# Does enabling LDAP over SSL and HTTP over SSL require two certificates?

Tags: http, ssl, ldap

I am a novice in SSL working on a Spring web application running directly off of an Apache Tomcat server. It is currently configured to be able to use LDAP (non-SSL) for authentication (this was set up by a previous developer). It also is running over http (also not SSL).

I want to be able to use both LDAPS and HTTPS.

My question is will I be able to use the same certificate to enable SSL for both LDAPS usage and HTTPS usage?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same certificate if:

- you use the same server name in both cases or
- if you have a certificate covering both names, with both names listed in the certificate, or
- if they have some common domain suffix and you have a relevant wildcard certificate

Remember that certificates are used to prove the identity of some remote endpoint, and it is typically based on the hostname of the endpoint, as shown in some URLs, either for HTTPS or LDAPS.

[RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125) describes how identity is checked with certificates. Section 6 for the generic idea, and then appendix B.2 for HTTPS case and B.3 for LDAPS. They both use the name.

Comment: @mvreijn Mostly good edit, but part of it was bizarre, by which I mean meaning-destroying. Fixed it.